# Ansible built-in COPY task - does it run only in serial manner?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I can't find any documentation that explicitly states this, but if I have a playbook that has a copy task and is triggered on multiple hosts concurrently, I am noticing that when it comes to the COPY task, only one play executes at a time. Playbook executions on all the other hosts pauses, and then one of them resumes when the first one completes. And so on.

Is there any documentation that someone can point to, which says that COPY will run exclusively? I am thinking that it could be implemented this way by Ansible to avoid inefficiencies in disk seeks etc. Any pointers?

(If it indeed runs serially by default, is there any way to run them in parallel? Of course only if it doesn't become counterproductive).

Here is an example task I have. This copies a single ISO image (from the controller node) to a number of target hosts. I am on **Ansible v2.9.4**.

```yaml
- name: Copying binaries to target hosts
  copy:
    src: "{{ binary_local_path }}"
    dest: "{{ binary_remote_path }}"
  register: result
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the tasks run in parallel. Use [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). It will provide you with [details](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#runner-artifacts-directory-hierarchy). For example, given a playbook

```yaml
shell> cat test-copy/test-28.yml 
- hosts: test_01,test_02,test_03
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: /etc/passwd
        dest: /tmp/test
```

the command

```sh
shell> ansible-runner run test-copy -i ID01 -p test-28.yml
```

creates the details

```sh
shell> tree test-copy/artifacts/ID01/
test-copy/artifacts/ID01/
├── command
├── fact_cache
├── job_events
│   ├── 10-c9ee2f18-9f8e-4b51-a5a5-81c7353131fb.json
│   ├── 1-45a882a8-a95d-4026-a374-fa3be0dc26bb.json
│   ├── 2-3d614ae4-866b-7e82-3e7a-000000000008.json
│   ├── 3-3d614ae4-866b-7e82-3e7a-00000000000a.json
│   ├── 4-4eb0b550-3537-4120-9fad-6ed5a7703f0d.json
│   ├── 5-e305a7d2-d3bd-409b-963e-4b214a6a129b.json
│   ├── 6-6949e8cc-458a-4626-b2cb-68a244e308af.json
│   ├── 7-e1049b61-5c27-4627-b5b0-181533cb458a.json
│   ├── 8-722940a2-1edd-45b7-8418-697e6f728000.json
│   └── 9-b5983d4c-6973-4626-93ba-462c00cbfa78.json
├── rc
├── status
└── stdout

2 directories, 14 file
```

Review *job_events*. Simplify the analysis. Install the role *vbotka.ansible_lib*

```sh
shell> ansible-galaxy role install vbotka.ansible_lib
```

and use the task [*al_runner_events*](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-lib/blob/master/tasks/al_runner_events.yml) in the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat test-29.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    al_runner_events_dir: test-copy/artifacts/ID01/job_events
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: vbotka.ansible_lib
        tasks_from: al_runner_events
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.counter }}
              {{ item.event_data.host }}
              {{ item.event_data.task }}
              start: {{ item.event_data.start }}
              end: {{ item.event_data.end }}"
      loop: "{{ al_runner_events_list|sort(attribute='counter') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.counter }}"
      when: item.event_data.duration|default(0) > 0
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test-29.yml | grep msg
  msg: '7 test_03 copy start: 2020-10-30T07:19:55.541914 end: 2020-10-30T07:20:00.078211'
  msg: '8 test_01 copy start: 2020-10-30T07:19:55.520058 end: 2020-10-30T07:20:00.239671'
  msg: '9 test_02 copy start: 2020-10-30T07:19:55.527841 end: 2020-10-30T07:20:00.460820'
```

It can be seen the *copy* tasks were running in parallel.

---

If you set [*serial: 1*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial)

```yaml
shell> cat test-copy/test-28.yml
- hosts: test_01,test_02,test_03
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: /etc/passwd
        dest: /tmp/test
```

The *copy* tasks will be running in serial

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test-29.yml | grep msg
  msg: '5 test_01 copy start: 2020-10-30T10:12:55.830801 end: 2020-10-30T10:12:59.696363'
  msg: '9 test_02 copy start: 2020-10-30T10:12:59.727570 end: 2020-10-30T10:13:02.787844'
  msg: '13 test_03 copy start: 2020-10-30T10:13:02.820704 end: 2020-10-30T10:13:05.835439'
```